# Java 8 Stream filter object list by key. Exclude key that are in List & get String

Tags: java, dictionary, filter, java-stream, reduce

I want to exclude the objects from a list with the id's contained in another list of Id's and get a String of field names.`" Care, Safe"`

Example:

```
public interface Selectable {
     Long getId();
     String getName();
}
```

I have a  `list<Selectable> tenants`

```
id, name
34, "House"
35, "Care"
36, "Villa"
37, "Safe"
```

and another `List<Long> idTenantsWithAlerts`

```
id
34
36
```

I need the result String **tenantsNoAlerts** to be `"Care, Safe"`

I don't have many experience with java8 streams, so I tried same filter, map and reduce ... but no luck.

Comment: `List<Long, String>`? That type doesn't exist.

Comment: @Polygnome. No I will set the code

Comment: @Eklavya I set some  code ...

Comment: is it possible to have `tenants` as a `Map<Long, String>` rather than `List<Selectable>` ? If it is possible, then your stream filter would be more effective and simpler.

Comment: You could replace the `idTenantsWithAlerts` `List` with a `Set`. Its most used implementation, `HashSet`, has a lookup time complexity of *O(1)*.

Comment: I suspect your `List<Long> idTenantsWithAlerts` to be a `String`, am I right? I took your representation of the value(s) `"34,36"` as a first hint and your try to invoke `ten.getId().toString()` in the `map` call as another one. **Is `idTenantsWithAlerts` a `String` or a `List<Long>` or anything else?**

Comment: Thanks for the help @deHaar This List<Long> idTenantsWithAlerts is really like this. But before I converted to a String ... and then I set that code ... Next time I ask a question before ... going to so much mess :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter the list by `Id`, then `map`, then `collect` with a *joining collector* to *reduce* the `Stream` to a `String`.

```java
List<Selectable> tenants;
String tenantsNoAlerts = tenants.stream()
    .filter(entry -> !idTenantsWithAlerts.contains(entry.getId()))
    .map(entry -> entry.getName())
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Comment: I think it should be `!idTenantsWithAlerts.contains(entry.getId())` because those `id`s are to be excluded, otherwise this is likely to be what OP wants.

Comment: @deHaar yes! If you want to edit the change I then accept the answer. Thank you

Comment: @deHaar You are right, I missed inverting the condition. Thanks for the hint ;)